# Backward loop in Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, math

I need to loop backwards from i=n-2 to i = 0 to code this math formula:

[image: math formula]

```
for i in range(n-2,0):
    X[i] = Y[i]
    for m in range(i+1,n):

        X[i] = X[i] - T[i,m] * X[m]
```

It doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

All numbers from numpy arrays

Comment: `range(n - 2, 0)` will count up from `n-2` to `-1`. If you want to go backwards, you should do `range(n - 2, -1, -1)` so it counts backwards from `n-2` to `0` (the last index isn't included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to loop backward you can use the for loop like following

```
range(start, end, step)
```

the step is 1 by default. in your case, you have to specify the decrement in order the loop the work.